Not able to import the selenium packages in Java IDE. Throwing the type (i.e.. Selenium webdriver package) is not accessible
package com.EX1It
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class TestLibrariesSetUp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

}
Can someone help resolve this package accessibility issue?
